# call applet method from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, applet

i want to call a method startApp() ,located in the java applet file from a  java script file.

i tried the following method

```
   <APPLET  name="drops" code="BigDrops.class" width=700 height=650 ></APPLET>
```

document.drops.startApp();

but  it shows "has no method startApp()" when i looked in the console of the browser

But the strange fact i noticed is that this problem is occured in all computers except mine..the files are loaded in the dropbox.
When i run the applet using the dropbox url from my computer, it works fine
tell me why it does not work and also give the solution

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: ya..it shows "has no method startApp()" when i looked in the console

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html

Comment: LiveConnect behaviors changed at 7u25. Same JRE version and security slider on all computers? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html#lc-block

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call JApplet function from javascript is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438293/call-japplet-function-from-javascript-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @zakki  Interesting.  Perhaps you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

LiveConnect calls from JavaScript are limited under some security level from [7u21](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html) and [7u25](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html#lc-block).